# how to hide & disable fields that are dependent upon the value of another field(s) using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, symfony1

The code below works, but I have the following problems:

1. is this even the most efficient/elegant solution to get the desired result?  If not, can someone point me in the right direction?
2. on page load jQuery is not reading the value of the MainWidgetName (a select input) on the form... causing nothing to be displayed until a change is made to that field.
3. how to clear the values and disable the select input of the unused/unassociated fields upon change, or if javascript is disabled?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    '6' : $('#result1'),
    '7' : $('#result2'),
    '8' : $('#result3'),
    '9' : $('#result4'),
    '10': $('#result5'),
    '11': $('#result6')
  };

  $('#mainWidgetName').change(function() 
  {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() {$(this).hide(); });
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
   });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="simple">
    <?php echo $form['mainWidgetName']->renderRow(); ?>    
    <tr id="result1" style="display:none"><th><?php echo $form[‘widgetName1’]->renderLabel()  ?></th><td><?php echo $form['widgetName1']->render(); ?></td></tr>  
    <tr id="result2" style="display:none"><th><?php echo $form[‘widgetName2’]->renderLabel()  ?></th><td><?php echo $form['widgetName2']->render(); ?>t</td></tr>
    <tr id="result3" style="display:none"><th><?php echo $form[‘widgetName3’]->renderLabel()  ?></th><td><?php echo $form['widgetName3']->render(); ?></td></tr>
    <tr id="result4" style="display:none"><th><?php echo $form[‘widgetName4’]->renderLabel()  ?></th><td><?php echo $form['widgetName4']->render(); ?></td></tr>
    <tr id="result5" style="display:none"><th><?php echo $form[‘widgetName5’]->renderLabel()  ?></th><td><?php echo $form['widgetName5']->render(); ?></td></tr>​
    <tr id="result6" style="display:none"><th><?php echo $form[‘widgetName6’]->renderLabel()  ?></th><td><?php echo $form['widgetName6']->render(); ?></td></tr>​
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you made any research? http://api.jquery.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great plugin that achieved the result I was looking for:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-related-dependent-selects-plugin/